# ufw-init errors out with Bad argument DROP

Tags: iptables, ufw, gufw, nftables

I don't know unfortunately when it stopped working, because I was using it as a fire and forget solution. Not so long ago I checked it with `gufw` and was stunned to realize my machine is naked.

```
root@asus:/etc/ufw# dpkg -l | grep ufw
ii  gufw   19.10.0-2
ii  ufw    0.36-1


root@asus:/etc/ufw# dpkg -l | grep tables
ii  iptables               1.8.4-11
ii  iptables-dev:amd64     1.8.3-2
ii  libnftables1:amd64     0.9.3-2
ii  libnftnl11:amd64       1.1.5-1
ii  libxtables-dev:amd64   1.8.4-1
ii  libxtables12:amd64     1.8.4-1
ii  nftables               0.9.3-2
```

I'm running with a `5.3.0-3-amd64` kernel.

The actual error:

```
root@asus:/# ufw enable
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
Bad argument `DROP'
Error occurred at line: 4
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
Bad argument `-'
Error occurred at line: 4
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore: line 2 failed
Bad argument `-'
Error occurred at line: 3
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
Bad argument `-'
Error occurred at line: 3
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
Bad argument `-'
Error occurred at line: 3
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
Bad argument `-'
Error occurred at line: 3
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (nf_tables): Chain 'ufw-user-input' does not exist
Error occurred at line: 2
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
Bad argument `DROP'
Error occurred at line: 4
Try `ip6tables-restore -h' or 'ip6tables-restore --help' for more information.
Bad argument `-'
Error occurred at line: 4
Try `ip6tables-restore -h' or 'ip6tables-restore --help' for more information.
ip6tables-restore: line 2 failed
Bad argument `-'
Error occurred at line: 3
Try `ip6tables-restore -h' or 'ip6tables-restore --help' for more information.
Bad argument `-'
Error occurred at line: 3
Try `ip6tables-restore -h' or 'ip6tables-restore --help' for more information.
Bad argument `-'
Error occurred at line: 3
Try `ip6tables-restore -h' or 'ip6tables-restore --help' for more information.
Bad argument `-'
Error occurred at line: 3
Try `ip6tables-restore -h' or 'ip6tables-restore --help' for more information.
ip6tables-restore v1.8.4 (nf_tables): Chain 'ufw6-user-input' does not exist
Error occurred at line: 2
Try `ip6tables-restore -h' or 'ip6tables-restore --help' for more information.

Problem running '/etc/ufw/user.rules'
Problem running '/etc/ufw/user6.rules'
```

I haven't found any telling hits on this (a lot of ufw problems but not this type). I wonder if it's something with the kernel's `iptables` support, the fact that `nftables` package somehow got itself into the installed packages or something else? If I delete the `before*.rules` or `after*.rules` from `/etc/ufw` I get an error because of that, the scripts look for those files.

I wonder if anyone has the same error message for `ufw enable`. Right now my `ufw` is inactive.

```
root@asus:/etc/ufw# lsmod | grep tables
ip6_tables             36864  0
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               49152  17 xt_conntrack,nft_compat,xt_LOG,xt_multiport,xt_tcpudp,xt_hashlimit,xt_addrtype,xt_recent,ip6t_rt,xt_comment,ip6_tables,ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,xt_limit,xt_hl,xt_MASQUERADE,ip6t_REJECT
nf_tables             163840  46 nft_compat,nft_counter,nft_chain_nat,nft_limit
nfnetlink              16384  4 nft_compat,nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_tables
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error in Debian.

I switched back to iptables-legacy according to the information on this [site](https://wiki.debian.org/iptables).

Comment: Oh. So basically the compatibility provided by `nftables` is not 100% compatible with `iptables`? I'll explore this further. This could be basically a bug with the compatibility layer.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic: will `nftables` be replaced with the Berkeley packet filter? https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=BPFILTER-Linux-4.18

Comment: `update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy` + `update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy` solved it. Unbelievable. And I'm saying 'unbelievable' because I don't think ufw composes too complicated rules...